# Updates are not installing

Tags: updates

When I try to update any programs, it does not work, error message says files are missing. I have not tried anything to fix this issue.

Comment: You should give some more imformation. Try these commands in your terminal: `sudo apt-get update` `sudo apt-get upgrade` and edit your question and paste with the output.

Comment: What are the error messages saying?

Answer (score 0):

1-check your internet connectivity

2-ensure you dont need any proxy to use internet(or you must set the proxy)

3-open terminal and type `sudo apt-get update`

4-now you can update your programs.

--if you meet any error, tell about the exact error messages and other appropriate settings you have.